# Web Service through Intranet

Tags: php, html, web-services, wamp

I have a simple intranet with WAMP at work that I setup myself (nothing fancy, just few pages that shared local computers use to share data, search modify database and upload stuff on)

One of the functionalities is a log that people add stuff in and it shows on the home page as new information. With this I would like to make a web service, but I am wondering:

- Can I make a web service that will display the last log entry from the intranet but will be online? I would like for example, if I leave work and use my phone to activate the web service so it displays the last inserted log in the intranet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the web service from internet you have the following two options:

- use a VPN to your working net. You can access the web service *as if you were at work*
- Establish a NAT forward from your works router to the web server that hosts the service. Then you access the service like `http://OUTER_IP_OR_DYNDNS_AT_WORK:SERVICE_PORT`

I would advice to use VPN as it is *industry standard* for such things and much more secure.

Comment: Thanks I will check both options you mentioned. But I don't see if you read that this is not for internet, the pages aren't online, they are on the work intranet. With that said, I want to take data from closed intranet and post it online through some web service.

Comment: `Can I make a web service that will display the last log entry from the intranet but will be online` .. What means *will be online*?

Comment: IMO, it means whatever way I can get data from an intranet, pass it through to some online web service through router in some way so I can search and take the data from my phone when connected to the internet.

Comment: I've exactly answered this! :)

Comment: Found this under wikipedia searching VPN "Example use of a VPN Tunnel" this is exactly what I want. Thank you, I will research this and try implement it as best as I can :)

Comment: Yep! :) If you need to buy hardware for that VPN gateway (at work), check that your cell phone supports clients for that type of VPN. Note that there is a jungle full of different vendors and protocols out there. But no worry you'll find a way! ;) Mostly your DSL router will already support a type of VPN. Maybe you have luck and  your cellphone can connect with that. Good luck!

Comment: @hek2mgl You're on this site long enough to have this question recognized it as off-topic.

Comment: @LinusKleen This is no reason for a [downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). I think, maybe it can be moved to serverfault.com (or whatever), what wouldn't be fatal. But I think it is still programming related. At least a little bit and I had to solve this once too - as a programmer, not admin ;)